# Is there a way to enforce SSL or TLS in Active Directory?

Tags: ssl, active-directory

Apparently there is no way to set Active Directory to force TLS or SSL for binds. This means that by default, and maybe without any options to change, all passwords for LDAP BINDs to Active Directory go in the clear.

I tested several AD domains, and it seems they all support cleartext LDAP BINDs.

There should be a way to enforce that BINDs only happen after TLS or SSL is established.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You will probably get better answers on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Comment: Block port 363 on the host firewall

Comment: what's port 363? Maybe you are thinking of 636 (ldaps)... not sure how that would help. If you blocked 389, that might do the trick but it would hoze clients that expect to use 389 for StartTLS